# convert datetime into numeric sequence in R

Tags: r, datetime, sequence, numeric

I have data collected every 12 minutes for two consecutive days. These data are collected with POSIXct datetime format which is great to handle dates and times. However, I have a problem to plot my data.

My objective is to plot them in a sequence which goes from 0 to 48 (the number of hours for the two days).

Any idea to convert my datetime into a sequence from 0 to 48 in R??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: (1) Representative sample data provided by the original poster is usually better than whatever we can guess based on a description. It might be fairly trivial, but please add your own representative data so that we don't get into a spiral on incorrect data samples. (2) `as.numeric(time - min(time), units = "hours")` and you'll get `numeric` hours.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you need this

```
n <- seq( 0,48, length.out=(48*60)/12 )
head(n)
[1] 0.0000000 0.2008368 0.4016736 0.6025105 0.8033473 1.0041841

tail(n)
[1] 46.99582 47.19665 47.39749 47.59833 47.79916 48.00000
```

It gives you (48*60=2880 minutes divided by 12) 240 evenly spread numbers from 0 to 48.

Comment: Well, that is one of the possibilities I was thinking, However, to plot the hourly mean... would be still possible with this approach??

Comment: @RafaelBravo I'm not entirely sure how your objects look like, but you could simply take 5 observations and take the mean regardless of what lies under your x-tics (240 0-48 or 240 12 min time points).